# Code to get a list of all Google agenda items for one account

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to code a Google Scripts script to format and print more than one Google agenda in a single sheet.

I managed to get the code to achieve that.

But now I want to get and filter Google Calendars for one account in a form in a Google Sheet to select them before formatting. I know this is an HTML code. The Google Sheet add-on "calendar to sheet" made by [Californiadrims](https://californiadrims.com/complementos-de-google-apps/) is exactly what I want to do: list with check boxes of the calendars.

I will appreciate a little help or orientation (an example) of this HTML code.

Comment: English is fine, but please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and what didn't work. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: It's impossible for me to find even a little piece of code for this.